# Is the server without GPU is good for remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp, desktop, remote-desktop-gateway

I want to buy a server 4 cores Intel Xeon E3-1220 v5 (16 GB RAM) but without GPU. 
Is it OK to use as a remote desktop computer? 
I know that we need GPU to show images on the screen but I don't know on which side do we need a GPU. 
Do we need GPU on the server side to normaly show desktop screans via remore desktop or we need GPU on the client side? Or on both sides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All processing (including that of the graphics card) is done on the host computer. The power from the client computer doesn't matter as long as it has strength enough to run an RDP program.

That said, RDP strips down graphics to permit a fast response over the network.

Depending on what kind of software you want to run remotely it could be useful to have some gpu power or not.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I want to run a Debian OS with KDE Plasma 5.9. I need this server only for programming in the IDE and searching on the internet. Do I need a graphic card for these tasks? I see that Intel Xeon E3-1220 v5 has included Intel® HD Graphics P530. Is it enough for such tasks?

Comment: Should work. Keep it as light as possible!